# WPF Splash Window flip into main window

Tags: .net, wpf, animation

So, I've been looking around at some different methods for making a control "flip" around, but none seem to offer what I'm trying to do.

I have a Desktop app that shows a splash window while it is loading, then the splash window goes away and the main window opens.

I want to make the splash window close by becoming narrow until it disappears, then make the main window open with the same effect but reversed- that way it appears that the splash window flips around and becomes the main window. I am looking for it to look something similar to the way apps open in Windows 8 Modern UI view.

All of the other examples I've seen need a front and back object to display, which I don't really want- I just want each window to perform half the animation.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does 'front and back object' mean?  Is it two visuals in a grid that share the same surface?

Comment: You probably want to look into adding a `ScaleTransform` to the `RenderTransform` of each window, and then create a storyboard that animates the splashscreen's scaling from 100% to 0%, followed by animating the real window's scaling from 0% to 100%

Comment: @Garry: In the examples I was referencing, the objects were two different images (a front image and back image). For my purposes, the two objects are two different windows so they shouldn't be connected in any way- the splash window needs to go from open to narrow and the main window needs to go from narrow to open.

Comment: @Jon: I'll look into that, I may be incorrect but as far as I understood scaling was all four edges of the window?

Comment: @koresho, in that case you would select Nishant's answer below.  He describes a solution with is implicit in Jon's answer above.  You will need to combine both answers to complete the coding exercise.

Comment: @koresho, with a ScaleTransform, you can adjust the horizontal and vertical scaling independently. It sounds like you only want to animate the horizontal, which is entirely doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into adding a `ScaleTransform` to the `RenderTransform` of each window, and then create a storyboard that animates the splashscreen's horizontal scaling from 100% to 0%, followed by animating the real window's horizontal scaling from 0% to 100%. This will provide the shrinking / expanding effect you are looking for without the performance and layout problems inherent in animating the width of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question - "I just want each window to perform half the animation".
If you have two different Window objects then animate the splash window to narrow its width to zero and then hide/close it. And then Open the main window with zero width and animate it to its desired size.
If you have just one window object then skip the 'close window' step.
Let me know if you want me to write a code sample

Comment: Alrighty, that makes sense. I'd tried to animate the width property, but realized I was using the wrong animation type. Thanks!

Comment: Animating the width can result in some performance issues, as well as display issues depending on how the content is laid out. Using a RenderTransform will give better results.

Comment: @Jon: yeah, I saw that, so I made some code changes and now I'm implementing the scale via RenderTransform as you suggested. If you can add as an answer please do so.